# Does your team's faction limit affect hero choice?

Tags: dota-2

In recent months, I've started playing Dota-2. However, when playing match-made, un-ranked games, I've been able to choose any character, even though, according to the in-game lore and the wiki page, the heroes belong to either the Radiant *or* Dire.

[image: Dota Wiki's Hero page]

Is this intended? Does it change in other game modes? *(I've been playing **All Pick**.)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### History:

In DotA 1 in the early years the default mode (called "normal") would have limited both sides (**Sentinel** and **Scourge** in DotA 1, **Radiant** and **Dire** in DotA 2) to pick the heroes their sides are connected to. There was even a third party **neutral** which would be offered to both parties to pick from.

[image]

At some point the mode **All Pick** was introduced which allowed to pick any hero. Balancing was not done for this kind of setup at the start but since the mode became the most popular in public games DotA 1 started to get balanced around this mode until **Captains Mode** was the main focus of balance. Because **All Pick** became so famous there was no longer a need to have parties per se. I guess **Sentinel** and **Scourge** were kept to keep the theme of the game (Defense of the Ancients) and the lore (good vs evil) while the **neutral** party was split and added into the remaining two parties that you can see today.

### Bottom Line:

In DotA 2 these sides have no effect anymore other than being part of the lore or until Valve/Icefrog decide to include the modus **-normal** again.

#### Even more detail:

In Warcraft III (the normal game) you would pick heroes depending on your race(human,orc,etc) from your own altar. Furthermore you were able to purchase neutral heroes from taverns (everyone can access those).

The concept to buy heroes from taverns and to have neutral heroes in the first place was copied into DotA 1.

Here are three pictures representing DotA 1 hero selection showing the evolution of Taverns (examples):
[image]

Upper left picture shows that back in v6.09 each faction/side had its own taverns(3).

Upper right picture shows that later in v6.60 all taverns were stored in the upper left corner of the map. Each side of the triangle has 3 taverns which stand for an attribute (strength, agility, intelligence) and within each tavern lies one faction (sentinel, neutral, scourge).

The last picture shows the modern arrangement (v6.70) of the taverns without the neutral faction. From left to right we have two sentinel and two scourge taverns. From top to bottom we have strength, intelligence and agility.

Comment: nice answer.  I never played the original so interesting to see a bit of the history of dota

Comment: thanks. i could add that in Warcraft III (the normal game) you would pick heroes from your own altar(according to race[human,orc,etc]) and could purchase neutral heroes (anyone can access) from taverns. The concept to buy heroes from taverns and to have neutral heroes in the first place was copied into DotA 1.

Comment: Those were the days..

Answer (score 1):

No; you can pick any hero, regardless of your assigned faction (barring any other restrictions specific to your specific game mode, of course). Since the faction split has absolutely no effect on gameplay in Dota 2, the fact that specific heroes are categorized as "Radiant" and "Dire" currently serves basically two purposes:

1. For story/lore purposes.
2. It also serves to break up the hero selection screen in half vertically to make it a little easier to "read."

The original DotA map broke up the heroes into "Sentinel" and "Scourge" in much the same way.

Comment: Also in Warcraft 3 dota you had a mode where Sentinel could only pick Sentinel heroes and Scourge only Scourge heroes

Comment: @Panic i doubt that your second point is valid. The history of dota 1 dictates that there need to be two sides rather than valves "design" decision for dota 2. Any sources on your second point?

Comment: @Wandang Regardless of the history, the grid view *is* broken up that way. That's a current effect that the faction breakup has, regardless of the prior reasons or history involved. That's all I meant by it.

Answer (score 1):

The heroes are split between Dire and Radiant only for flavour and there are no limitations for piking one depending on your team.